# updated Jelly Bean Android Stack?

Tags: android, linux, api

Has the Android Stack seen any remarkable updates in Jelly Bean 4.1? I am referring to the stack of components and libraries as shown in this picture:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was at the Google I/O and at least at the session I did attend they did not present anything new. The core technology is the same - they've just introduced some new features in the Kernel & system like Triple Buffering.

The visualization you put in your post is abstract & generic enough to be correct ;)